# how to pass comma separated parameter to batch file and use if else in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have one batch file MyTest.bat

```
MyTest.bat

call "first.bat" 

call "second.bat" 

call "third.bat"
```

Now while executing MyTest.bat I will pass comma separated parameters like

call MyTest.bat first.bat,second.bat

now inside MyTest.bat I want to check which parameters are passed and based on those using if else condition

I want to execute internal statements.

for example something like it

```
MyTest.bat first.bat,second.bat

now inside 

I will check 

get all parameters list param[] = {first.bat,second.bat}

if param[i] ==  "first.bat" 

{

call "first.bat" 

}

else if param[i] ==  "second.bat" 


{

call "second.bat" 

}

else if param[i] ==  "third.bat" 


{

call "third.bat" 

}
```

// this assures that what parameters I passed only those statements gets executed not other.

The above code is just a pseudo code how can write actual MyTest.bat?

Comment: Why don't you simply comment out `call "third.bat" %1 %2`? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: how can i call both the scripts or if i want to execute more than one scripts ?

Comment: Every single line in MyTest.bat will be performed in the order it is listed. To call both first.bat and second.bat, simply include them in your file in the order in which you want them performed.

Comment: I want to execute it based on parameter passed not by any order

Comment: Open a command prompt window, enter `call /?` and read. Then enter `if /?` and read. Then enter `goto /?` and read. And finally edit your post and explain how do you start `MyTest.bat` and with which parameters, and what should the batch file do depending on the parameters.

Comment: I want to exceute `MyTest.bat` and pass it comma separate parameters which contains name of files what is inside `MyTest.bat` for example
I will pass `first.bat , second.bat` as parameter then while excecuting `MyTest.bat` i want to check which file name is passed if it is `first.bat,second.bat` then execute only that statement and ignore all other got it?

Comment: updated question with full description and pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next script requires another parameter order (list of batch names down to end all other parameters):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
rem usage: 33955749.bat name address "first script", second, third
:loop
  if "%~3" == "" goto :next
  if exist "%~n3.bat" (
    call "%~n3.bat" %1 %2
  ) else (
    echo can't found file; failed call "%~n3.bat" %1 %2 
  )
  shift /3
  goto :loop
:next
```

For debugging purposes, prepare sample files `"first script.bat"` and `second.bat`; ensure that `third.bat` does not exist:

```
==> >"first script.bat" echo @echo %~nx0 parameters: %%*=%*

==> >second.bat echo @echo %~nx0 parameters: %%*=%*

==> 2>NUL del third.bat
```

**Output** (shows independency on used [delimiters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters)):

```
==> 33955749 name address "first script", second, third
first script.bat parameters: %*=name address
second.bat parameters: %*=name address
can't found file; failed call "third.bat" name address

==> 33955749 name address "first script"  second; third
first script.bat parameters: %*=name address
second.bat parameters: %*=name address
can't found file; failed call "third.bat" name address
```

Another approach: fist parameter = list of comma-separated batch names surrounded with a pair of double quotes:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
rem usage: 33955749b "first script,second,third" name address
rem no spaces surrounding commas or names
rem wrong: 33955749b " first script , second, third" would fail
set "_names=%~1"
set "_names=%_names:,=","%"
rem debug echo _names="%_names%"
for  %%G in ("%_names%") do (
  if exist "%%~dpnG.bat" (
    call "%%~dpnG.bat" %2 %3
  ) else (
    echo can't found script; failed call "%%~dpnG.bat" %2 %3 
  )
)
```

**Output** (shows responsivity to used delimiters):

```
==> 33955749b "first script,second,third" name address
first script.bat parameters: %*=name address
second.bat parameters: %*=name address
can't found script; failed call "D:\bat\SO\third.bat" name address

==> 33955749b "first script, second,third" name address
first script.bat parameters: %*=name address
can't found script; failed call "D:\bat\SO\ second.bat" name address
can't found script; failed call "D:\bat\SO\third.bat" name address
```

Note that both `33955749.bat` and `33955749b.bat` scripts

- accept (partially or fully qualified) paths to called scripts, even with space(s);
- on the other hand, they both ignore file extension(s) even if supplied and force `.bat`.

For instance, `33955749 name address first.cmd second.cmd` would attempt to call `first.bat` and `second.bat`.

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G`, `%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: thanks helpful if anything else i will ping you  :) @ashuthinks twitter handler thanks

Comment: updated question with full description and pseudo code