# how to loop through all passsed parameter in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have one master batch file

> Master.bat which called 3 files `first.bat` , `second.bat` ,
>   `third.bat`

Now I want to pass parameters to `Master.bat` and based on parameter want to execute internal statements 
for example 
If I passed `Master.bat first` then `Master.bat` should execute only `call first.bat` not others.

```
Master.bat

call "first.bat" 

call "second.bat" 

call "third.bat"
```

How can I achieve this? If multiple parameters are also passed?How can I loop though?
answer I accepted works fine for me but 
When I pass extra other parameters it fails :( like below
`Master.bat first,second parameter1 parameter2`
now When I try to execute above it only exceutes first.bat 
Code for `Master.bat` is

```
@echo off
:LOOP
if "%1"=="" goto ENDLOOP
call "%1" %3 %2 
shift
goto LOOP
:ENDLOOP
```

> %1 should take `first,second` %2 should take `parameter1` %2 should
>   take `parameter2`

Comment: Seems like it would be just as easy to execute the batch files you want by just chaining them together instead of using a main batch file to execute them.  Less to type! `C:\BatchFiles>first & second` or `C:\BatchFiles>first & third`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass comma separated parameter to batch file and use if else in batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955749/how-to-pass-comma-separated-parameter-to-batch-file-and-use-if-else-in-batch-fil)

Comment: Trying to understand the relation between your previous question and this one. Again you can just chain the commands instead of having a separate batch file to do all the shifting. `C:\BatchFiles>first a b & second c d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `shift`:

```
@echo off
:LOOP
if "%1"=="" goto ENDLOOP
call "%1"
shift
goto LOOP
:ENDLOOP
```

The first passed parameter is always stored in `%1`, the second one in `%2` the 3rd in `%3` and so on. The `shift` command moves the index to the right. The old %1 is lost, %2 becomes %1, %3 becomes %2 and so on. This way you can simply iterate over all passed parameters until you've shifted as often as there are parameters. Then %1 becomes empty and you break the loop with `goto ENDLOOP`.

**[EDIT]** According to your comment here is how to do what you are trying:

```
@echo off
:LOOP
if "%1"=="" goto ENDLOOP
call "%1" %2 %3
shift
shift
shift
goto LOOP
:ENDLOOP
```

If you are calling `master.bat a.bat b c x.bat y z` this will result in calling `a.bat b c` and `x.bat y z`.

Comment: where to use if statement? like if parameter is `first` then execute `first.bat` or what If i passed more than one parameters like `Master.bat first,second` it means execute both first.bat and second.bat

Comment: When you enter the loot for the first time first.bat is stored in %1 so it's being executed by `call %1`. Afer the first iteration %1 is second.bat so second.bat is being executed. Just don't use `,` as a separator. If you want to use `,` instead of spaces to separate your parameters, the whole file `first.bat,second.bat` will be interpreted as one single parameter. In this case you will need to split it by `,` but this is a whole different question.

Comment: this works for me but not for multiple parameters :( i tried like 

`@echo off
:LOOP
if "%1"=="" goto ENDLOOP
call "%1" %2 %3
shift
goto LOOP
:ENDLOOP` 
called Master.bat first,second param111 param222

Comment: Please update your question. The points you are asking for are not stated in the question text itself.

Comment: This solution chokes on `"%1"==""` when the argument is a filename that contains a space.

Answer (score 2):

Your batch file could do this in more than one way:

- the most common is to call successively the first parameter `%1` and use [`shift`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491002.aspx) to discard that, then [`if`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490920.aspx) to check if there are more parameters and [`goto`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490914.aspx) to return to the top of a loop.

  `:loop
       call "%1"
       shift
       if not "x%1"=="x' goto loop`
- alternatively, your script could process the command-line with [`for`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx):

  `for %%n in ( %* ) do call "%%n"`

Based on comment, OP may also have in mind a case where the parameters are comma-separated lists.  The `for` command can do this (with a more complicated example) using the `delims=` option, by constructing a variable to use as the built-up command, adding the split-off tokens to it and finally executing the resulting built-up command.  That probably should be a separate question.  For discussion purposes, see *[How do I get a for loop to work with a comma delimited string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112694/how-do-i-get-a-for-loop-to-work-with-a-comma-delimited-string)*

Comment: what If i passed more than one parameters like Master.bat first,second it means execute both first.bat and second.bat

Comment: That wasn't in the original question, but `for` (read the documentation) can step through a list with a specific delimiter).

Comment: @ThomasDickey, I agree with you on just using a basic `FOR` command.  It matches the users description perfectly if you ask me.  Simple as pie.